# Cut Dates into Weekly Intervals in Reverse from Current Day

Tags: r, sorting, date, dplyr, cut

I am having a hard time cutting a series of dates into weekly intervals from the present day. I can cut the dates just fine using the cut function, but I want the LAST week to be a full 7 day week.  Here is the data:

```
df_lim %>%
  mutate(weekly = as.Date(cut(pub_date, breaks = "week"))) %>%
  group_by(weekly, site) %>% 
  mutate(weekly_sum = sum(n)) %>%
  select(pub_date, weekly, weekly_sum) %>%
  print(n=500)

 site    pub_date   weekly     weekly_sum
   <chr>   <date>     <date>          <int>
 1 biorxiv 2020-01-19 2020-01-13          1
 2 biorxiv 2020-01-21 2020-01-20         15
 3 biorxiv 2020-01-22 2020-01-20         15
 4 biorxiv 2020-01-23 2020-01-20         15
 5 biorxiv 2020-01-24 2020-01-20         15
 6 biorxiv 2020-01-25 2020-01-20         15
 7 biorxiv 2020-01-26 2020-01-20         15
 8 biorxiv 2020-01-27 2020-01-27         18
 9 biorxiv 2020-01-28 2020-01-27         18
10 biorxiv 2020-01-29 2020-01-27         18
11 biorxiv 2020-01-30 2020-01-27         18
12 biorxiv 2020-01-31 2020-01-27         18
13 biorxiv 2020-02-02 2020-01-27         18
14 biorxiv 2020-02-03 2020-02-03          9
15 biorxiv 2020-02-04 2020-02-03          9
16 biorxiv 2020-02-07 2020-02-03          9
17 biorxiv 2020-02-08 2020-02-03          9
18 biorxiv 2020-02-10 2020-02-10         14
19 biorxiv 2020-02-11 2020-02-10         14
20 biorxiv 2020-02-12 2020-02-10         14
21 biorxiv 2020-02-13 2020-02-10         14
22 biorxiv 2020-02-14 2020-02-10         14
23 biorxiv 2020-02-15 2020-02-10         14
24 biorxiv 2020-02-18 2020-02-17         26
25 biorxiv 2020-02-19 2020-02-17         26
26 biorxiv 2020-02-20 2020-02-17         26
27 biorxiv 2020-02-21 2020-02-17         26
28 biorxiv 2020-02-24 2020-02-24         10
29 biorxiv 2020-02-27 2020-02-24         10
30 biorxiv 2020-02-28 2020-02-24         10
31 biorxiv 2020-03-02 2020-03-02         33
32 biorxiv 2020-03-03 2020-03-02         33
33 biorxiv 2020-03-04 2020-03-02         33
34 biorxiv 2020-03-05 2020-03-02         33
35 biorxiv 2020-03-06 2020-03-02         33
36 biorxiv 2020-03-07 2020-03-02         33
37 biorxiv 2020-03-08 2020-03-02         33
38 biorxiv 2020-03-09 2020-03-09         27
39 biorxiv 2020-03-10 2020-03-09         27
40 biorxiv 2020-03-12 2020-03-09         27
41 biorxiv 2020-03-14 2020-03-09         27
42 biorxiv 2020-03-15 2020-03-09         27
43 biorxiv 2020-03-17 2020-03-16         30
44 biorxiv 2020-03-20 2020-03-16         30
45 biorxiv 2020-03-21 2020-03-16         30
46 biorxiv 2020-03-22 2020-03-16         30
47 biorxiv 2020-03-23 2020-03-23         32
48 biorxiv 2020-03-24 2020-03-23         32
49 biorxiv 2020-03-25 2020-03-23         32
50 biorxiv 2020-03-26 2020-03-23         32
51 biorxiv 2020-03-27 2020-03-23         32
52 biorxiv 2020-03-28 2020-03-23         32
53 biorxiv 2020-03-29 2020-03-23         32
54 biorxiv 2020-03-30 2020-03-30         64
55 biorxiv 2020-03-31 2020-03-30         64
56 biorxiv 2020-04-01 2020-03-30         64
57 biorxiv 2020-04-02 2020-03-30         64
58 biorxiv 2020-04-03 2020-03-30         64
59 biorxiv 2020-04-04 2020-03-30         64
60 biorxiv 2020-04-05 2020-03-30         64
61 biorxiv 2020-04-06 2020-04-06         54
62 biorxiv 2020-04-08 2020-04-06         54
63 biorxiv 2020-04-09 2020-04-06         54
64 biorxiv 2020-04-10 2020-04-06         54
65 biorxiv 2020-04-11 2020-04-06         54
```

What I would like is for the "weekly" variable to be formed from today backwards, so that the end of the frame would look like this, with a full week included in the most recent weekly block.

```
...

59 biorxiv 2020-04-04 2020-03-29       
60 biorxiv 2020-04-05 2020-04-06        
61 biorxiv 2020-04-06 2020-04-06         
62 biorxiv 2020-04-08 2020-04-06         
63 biorxiv 2020-04-09 2020-04-06         
64 biorxiv 2020-04-10 2020-04-06         
65 biorxiv 2020-04-11 2020-04-06
```

I have tried a bunch of things with setting the "right" parameter as "TRUE" or "FALSE" and nothing seems to work. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you use breaks="week" the week will always start on either Monday or Sunday based on this option: "start.on.monday =".  So if you always want to have the last 7 days be a week, then the breaks need to change to "7 days"

Comment: Thank you!  That was something I tried - for some reason the "cut" function is not working when I do that. It just cuts it into individual days.  Is there a syntax issue or something that I could fix?